# Python: Getting variable name out of List within For loop

Tags: python, pandas, variables

How to get a variable name out of a List within a for loop.

example:

```
List = ['a','b','c','d']
for i in List:
    var_i_ = something
```

so for each letter in list there should be a new variable name like:

```
var_a_ = something
var_b_ = something
var_c_ = something
var_d_ = something
```

So i could call use it in pandas as well

```
List = ['a','b','c','d']
for i in List:
    df_i_ = something

df_a_ = something
df_b_ = something
df_c_ = something
df_d_ = something
```

each needs to be a different dataframe.
I need it as a search function to save data as csv or something else.

Comment: any reason why you need it?

Comment: That's a bad idea. Learn about lists and dictionaries instead.